# Group By Error msg8120 When I use in my function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am getting 8120 error when i use GROUP BY function. How can i solve it?

**My output :**

[image]

**When i use GROUP BY :**

[image]

**I want such a output:**

[image]

My Source Code:

```
WITH Numbers (Number) AS
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM (
        VALUES
        (NULL),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(20),(28),(30),(40),(50),(100),(496),(500),(1000),(8128),(10000)
    ) Numbers (Number)
),
PerfectNumberCandidates AS
(
    SELECT 
        Number,
        1 AS IndexNumber,
        0 AS DivisorSum,
        CAST('' AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS Summation
    FROM Numbers
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        Number,
        IndexNumber +1,
        CASE WHEN Number%(IndexNumber+1)=0 THEN IndexNumber+1 +  DivisorSum  ELSE  DivisorSum END AS DivisorSum,
        CASE WHEN Number%(IndexNumber+1)=0 THEN CAST(CAST(Summation AS varchar (1000)) + '+' + CAST(IndexNumber +1 AS varchar(1000))AS varchar(1000)) ELSE Summation END AS Summation
    FROM PerfectNumberCandidates
    WHERE IndexNumber+1 < Number
    
    
),
PerfectNumbers AS
(
    SELECT
        Number,
        CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT('1',Summation),'='),DivisorSum+1) AS Summation
    FROM PerfectNumberCandidates
    WHERE DivisorSum+1 = Number AND DivisorSum > 1
    GROUP BY Number -- HERE!!! 
    
)
SELECT
    *
FROM PerfectNumbers
ORDER BY Number
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10000)
```

-------------------------------------------------.---------------------------------------------------

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I think I'm using it in the wrong where.

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified the code a bit, but the problem is clearly here:

```
PerfectNumbers AS (
    SELECT Number,
           CONCAT('1', Summation, '=', DivisorSum+1) AS Summation
-----------------------^ --------------^
    FROM PerfectNumberCandidates
    WHERE DivisorSum+1 = Number AND DivisorSum > 1
    GROUP BY Number -- HERE!!! 
   )
```

It is not clear what you intend.  One might guess that no aggregation is needed:

```
PerfectNumbers AS (
    SELECT Number,
           CONCAT('1', Summation, '=', DivisorSum+1) AS Summation
    FROM PerfectNumberCandidates
    WHERE DivisorSum+1 = Number AND DivisorSum > 1
   )
```

Or perhaps some aggregation function:

```
PerfectNumbers AS (
    SELECT Number,
           MAX(CONCAT('1', Summation, '=', DivisorSum+1)) AS Summation
    FROM PerfectNumberCandidates
    WHERE DivisorSum+1 = Number AND DivisorSum > 1
    GROUP BY Number -- HERE!!! 
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

for you output. Just use distinct keyword and remove group by clause.

```
    PerfectNumbers AS
(
    SELECT
        distinct Number,
        CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT('1',Summation),'='),DivisorSum+1) AS Summation
    FROM PerfectNumberCandidates
    WHERE DivisorSum+1 = Number AND DivisorSum > 1
    --GROUP BY Number -- HERE!!!
```

)